# ggplot2 draw word surface temperature mismatched with word shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I wana draw a worldwide temperature distribute pic, with world shape file as a basemap then draw the temperature layer on top of it, but the longitude range of the shape file is from -180 to 180, the temperature data gathered from the NetCDF file is from 0 to 360, I tried to edit the basemap's longitude range ,but failed on the picture

could someone tell me how to deal with is problem?

```
    library(RNetCDF)
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
setwd("F:\\Programing\\Rnetcdf")
f<-open.nc("Soong.nc")

basemap<-readShapeSpatial("world.shp")
head(basemap)
shore <- fortify(basemap)
#shore$long<-shore$long+180
head(shore)
var.inq.nc(f,"TMP_P0_L109_GLL0")
apt<-var.get.nc(f,"APTMP_P0_L103_GLL0")

lon<-var.get.nc(f,"lon_0")
lat<-var.get.nc(f,"lat_0")


newlon<-rep(lon,each=length(lat))
newlat<-rep(lat,length(lon))
newapt<-as.vector(t(apt))

draw<-as.data.frame(cbind(newlat,newlon,newapt))
head(draw)


finaldraw<-ggplot(data=draw,aes(x=newlon,y=newlat,fill=newapt))+geom_raster(interpolate=T)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(7)), na.value = NA) +
  geom_polygon(data = shore, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), color = "black",fill="NA") +
  theme_bw() +

finaldraw
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
newlon[newlon>180]<-newlon[newlon>180]-360
```

after thinking, I finally draw a pic like this